# Laravel Format Array Data to Table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to create a table in my blade template. When i loop through the array once, i get the following error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` .

When i loop twice, i get an incorrect table format.

My blade template looks like this :

[image: current table]

```
@foreach($checkins as $index=>$opt)
          @foreach($checkins as $index=>$opt)
             @foreach($opt as $key => $value)
               <tr> {{$key}} </tr>
               <td> {{$value}}  </td>    
             @endforeach    
                                                        
         @endforeach
```

My controller looks like this, i converted the latitude and longitude to an actual location using the getAddress function :

```
if($request->has('search')) {
            $checkins = Checkin::with(['user'])->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->paginate(setting('record_per_page', 15));
        } else {
            $checkins = Checkin::with(['user'])->get();
        }

        $title = "Manage Checkins";

        
        $checkins = $checkins->map(function ($checkin) {

            $location = $this->getAddress($checkin->lat,$checkin->long);

            return [
                'location' => $location,
                'student' => $checkin->user->first_name. ' ' .$checkin->user->first_name,
                'supervisor' => $checkin->supervisor === null ? '' : $checkin->supervisor->first_name. ' ' .$checkin->supervisor->last_name  ,
                'created_at' => $checkin->created_at,
            ];
        });

        return view('checkins.index', compact('checkins', 'title'));
```

The array that looks like this :

```
[
{
location: "Government of Southern Sudan Nairobi Liason Office, 5th Avenue Ngong, Hurlingham, Nairobi, P. O. BOX 41362, Kenya",
student: "Super Admin Super Admin",
supervisor: "Super Admin Admin",
created_at: null
},
{
location: "Kajiado, Kenya",
student: "Test Test",
supervisor: "Super Admin Admin",
created_at: "2021-07-06T12:13:54.000000Z"
},
{
location: "Murang`a, Central Kenya, Kenya",
student: "Test Test",
supervisor: "Super Admin Admin",
created_at: "2021-07-06T12:16:19.000000Z"
}
]
```

Any assistance/links on how i can display the keys as the values and the actual values below the keys will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First loop return each individual item of associative array and second value loop each associative array to key value pair

```
     @foreach($checkins as $key=>$value)
           @foreach($value as $iKey=>$iValue)
           <tr>          
              <td> {{$iKey}} </td>
              <td> {{$iValue}}  </td>    
           </tr>
                                                                    
        @endforeach  
 @endforeach
```